# More efficient reading files vector or set or other method

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I made my own Binary search tree and a AVL tree. My assignment is to do this:

> First, create a data structure named SequenceMap that has as data members a string and a set of strings. This will be the data that we store in our trees and passed in to the template tree classes. This class should be comparable using the string member as the comparison key by overloading the operator< function.

It's just a suggestion I asked if i can use vectors, but i was wondering what is faster to store my text files and compare them against each other? Both text files are less than 2MB. Part of my assignment is to be efficient as possible in my code.

Comment: When you compare, are you looking for identical sequence or permutations?

Comment: this is like RNA and enzymes     so identical sequence

Comment: Efficient in memory usage, CPU usage, or computational time?

Comment: memory and computational time

Comment: If you are going to compare sequences, then certainly a `std::vector` would be best, followed by `std::deque` as second choice.  I'm not sure how your search trees are relevant, since sequence comparison requires only a front-to-back pass through both containers.  Are you doing a substring search, or maximum common substring, or?